# not sure why the output is 1 1, instead of 1123?

Tags: python-3.x

I took a quiz, the output for this following code is `1 1` instead of `1 1 2 3`. And the explanitaion for this answer is that when the code encounter the `break`(when it reach `2`) ,then loops stop.

I understand that the loops stop when it reach `2`, but since `print()` has the same indentation as `if()` statement, I thought they are excuted seperately, 
(but both still under `for` loop). So when `number` reaches `2`, even if the loop stops, it will still execute the `print()`, for it is still under `for` loops. Hence, the result is the `1 1 2 3`. And no matter what `if()` statement is, the result is the same.

```
numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3]
for number in numbers:
  if number % 2 == 0:
    break
  print(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the commands are interpreted in order. When the `if` condition becomes true, the `break` exits the `for` loop before the `print` can execute. The first two loops the `break` is skipped since `1 % 2 == 0` is false, but `2 % 2 == 0` is true exiting the loop before getting to `3` which would also be true and print... if the loop hadn't already exited.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It makes sense now!!

Answer (score 2):

When the `break` statement executes the execution pointer goes to the next statement outside the loop, not the statement after the `if` block containing the `break` statement, so the `print` function is not called once `break` is executed as the execution is then outside the loop.